# "Net::Netconf::Manager" converts underscore in RPC request to hyphen

Tags: perl, ietf-netconf

I am using
[`Net::Netconf::Manager`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Netconf::Manager)
to query a device with RPC commands. In the RPC commands I should send a list of arguments, so I'm adding query arguments in a hash. One such argument is `verbosity_level`

Please note I am using underscore `_` in this argument. When I print the hash, it is still underscore.

But when I print the XML RPC request that is sent to the device, the argument is changed to `verbosity-level`

```
<verbosity-level>abcd</verbosity-level>
```

instead of

```
<verbosity_level>abcd</verbosity_level>
```

So the device says it does not know such argument.

Why is the underscore gets converted to hyphen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that does this is on line 492 of
[`Net/Netconf/Device.pm`](https://metacpan.org/source/JUNIPER/Net-Netconf-1.04/lib/Net/Netconf/Device.pm#L492). It's a simple substitution, and there's no comment to explain why it's there

All I can think of to do is to comment out that line

```
($tag = $field) =~ s/_/-/g
```

and replace it with

```
$tag = $field
```

which should get things going for you. In the mean time, you could perhaps email the *Juniper Networks Perl Team* at **netconf-support@juniper.net** and ask about it. If you do, please let us know the response

Comment: Probably an artifact of Junos not having any *underscores* in their XML tags and adding some sugar in objectifying the RPC requests.   [Some examples show it done on their methods](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos13.2/topics/task/program/netconf-perl-client-application-submitting-requests.html). I would guess that there hasn't been a lot of other vendors doing netconf until recently.

Comment: Thanks Borodin. I have raised an issue in netconf-perl API in github. Seems like they are standardizing only to have hyphens in RPC requests instead of underscores. The issue can be tracked in the following link https://github.com/Juniper/netconf-perl/issues/35